# Struts 2 maven progect fails to run with struts.convention.classes.reload param

Tags: java, maven, struts2

Struts 2 maven progect fails to run with struts.convention.classes.reload param in web.xml.
So any idea about this? Thanks!

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>struts.convention.classes.reload</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I am getting this failure:

> авг 23, 2014 2:06:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   filterStart SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.struts2.convention.classloader.ReloadingClassLoader.(ReloadingClassLoader.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.initReloadClassLoader(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:255)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:52)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:200)
>     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:360)   at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:403)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)    at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>
> авг 23, 2014 2:06:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>   SEVERE: Error filterStart авг 23, 2014 2:06:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start SEVERE: Context [/ch04]
>   startup failed due to previous errors авг 23, 2014 2:06:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
>   SEVERE: The web application [/ch04] created a ThreadLocal with key of
>   type [null] (value
>   [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@15dc5d3]) and a value
>   of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@166deeb]) but
>   failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very
>   likely to create a memory leak. авг 23, 2014 2:06:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
>   SEVERE: The web application [/ch04] created a ThreadLocal with key of
>   type [null] (value
>   [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@b53bf3]) and a value
>   of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@72cee1]) but
>   failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very
>   likely to create a memory leak.

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3163